# Global java objects

Tags: java

I am writing a program which generates random numbers. In each of my methods I am creating an object which does the same thing in each method and I am giving it the same name each time. Is this bad practice? Would it be better to include it as a global object like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomNumbers {

Random rand = new Random();

public int random() {
    int result;
    result = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    return result;  
}

public int topNumber(int firstTopNumber){
    int result;
    result = rand.nextInt(firstTopNumber) + 1;
    return result;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomNumbers {

public int random() {
    int result;
    Random rand = new Random();
    result = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    return result;  
}

public int topNumber(int firstTopNumber){
    int result;
    Random rand = new Random();
    result = rand.nextInt(firstTopNumber) + 1;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your first scenario doesn't use a "global" object (there are no global-scoped variables in Java), but it does avoid having to keep reinstantiating a new `Random` object each time you need a number.  So I prefer it to the second scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in using a global variable for a purpose like this one. Actually your methods are not `static` so you wouldn't declare a global object, just a member variable. But I'm assuming that these methods should be static, since they are utility methods, then a private `static final variable` is a good thing (and avoid reseeding the sequence at each invocation), eg:

```
class RandomNumbers {
  private final static Random r = new Random();

  public static int topNumber(int firstTopNumber) {
   return r.nextInt(firstTopNumber) + 1;
  }
}
```

Mind that a variable shared between multiple methods (`static` or not) is not always a good thing, in this case you have a stateless object (actually it has state but it's irrelevant) so using it from any method is not a problem, but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

Before using a member variable the following should be checked.

1. The type of the instance variable should be thread safe (Random is thread safe) or the access-or methods should be synchronized.

2.Cross check the API document. See the quote below from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

> Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs.